# what is the use of qty_invoiced column in sales_order_item table?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sales-order, sales-order-item

I want to know that what is the use qty_invoiced column in the sales_order_item table in Magento 2.
[image]

Comment: sales_order_items table  in qty_invoiced column used for store number of qty invoice are created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has a feature to invoice a qty as per defined by admin.

e.g customer placed an order with 10 qty but for some reason customer want 5 qty only or instore only  5 available now admin want to procced order with 5 qty only and need to generate invoice for 5 products.so, admin will add 5 qty on invoice creation time instead of 10.

So,In *`sales_order_item`*  table *`qty_invoiced`*  filed will store data for that order.

hope you get it now